# Janus GridEX: find if header is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, janus, gridex

Currently when I double click on any grid item, below event is fired. This includes if I double click on headers as well.

Is there a way I can differentiate between header or rows clicked? SelectedItem position is always > 0

```
this.grdItems = new Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX();
...
this.grdItems.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.grdItems_DoubleClick);

private void grdItems_DoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (grdItems.SelectedItems!=null && grdItems.SelectedItems[0].Position >= 0)
        {
          //doing something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the `HitTest()` method

Declare your variables

```
public int MLastX { get; set; }
public int MLastY { get; set; }
```

Have a method to capture the co-ordinates of the last mouse click

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the MouseDown event of the grdSearch control. On a mousedown the click co-ordinates
///  is set.  This method is used to determine whether you have clicked on a gridrow cell in the method above
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="MouseEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
private void grdSearch_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MLastX = e.X;
    MLastY = e.Y;
}
```

Check if that click was in a cell

```
//check whether you have clicked in a cell 
if (grdSearch.HitTest(MLastX, MLastY) == GridArea.Cell)
{
   //now only execute the rest
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void mxGridExJanus1_RowDoubleClick(object sender, Janus.Windows.GridEX.RowActionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != RowType.Record) return;

    // row clicked
}
```